# Why quick sort will never have stack overflow?

Tags: c, sorting

> Assume that a computer system has a heap of 2GB and that the size of the call stack for an application is 1MB. Quicksort is used to sort an array that is stored on the heap (i.e. it is stored in the computer's internal memory not on a file). Assume that each recursive call to quicksort requires 256 bytes to be allocated to the call stack. Explain why the call to quicksort will not result in a stack overflow regardless of the size of the array being sorted. You should assume that the call to quicksort results in the average case O Notation running time for the algorithm.

My problem here is that if the number of elements stored in the heap is very large, it may use the memory more than 1MB since the recursive functions will call large amount of times. So how can it not cause the stack overflow?

Comment: The size of the elements being sorted is irrelevant since you only use *pointers* to those elements.

Comment: The usual trick is to employ tail recursion on the larger half while only recursion only on the smaller. This gives you a logarithmic worst-case depth instead in case of unbalanced linear one.

Comment: Here's a hint: When you increase the size of the data, does the amount used on the heap grow faster than the amount used on the stack? Will it run out of heap space before it runs out of stack space?

Comment: @doynax - The question may not allow recursion on smaller partition and looping on the larger partition. It only allows for the assumption that running time complexity is average case. See wiki article for [average case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Average-case_analysis). If sorting 2GB of bytes, there are only 256 possible pivot values, so that won't be an issue. For sorting 1GB of 16 bit elements, assuming near random data, using wiki percentile formula, stack space is about 37KB, so not an issue.